# Splitting different lengths of lines in text file and storing in string variables C++

Tags: c++, input

I am working on taking data from a text file and storing them in an array of linked lists. Each line in the text file begins with a movie name and the following strings are names of actors in the movie. It is formatted like so:

```
The_Other_Side_of_Joey Eric_Kahnler Gordon_Harris Elliott_Crawford William_Maxwell James_Fuller
Paradise_View Kaoru_Kobayashi Jun_Togawa Haruomi_Hosono Shinzoku_Ogimi Tomi_Taira Yoko_Taniyama Lily
The_Pecos_Pistol Forrest_Taylor Tex_Williams Smokey_Rogers Deuce_Spriggins Barbara_Payton Bill_Cassady
```

As you can see each line has a different number of actors. I am planning on making the movie name the head of the linked list and the following nodes will be the actors in the movie. To begin I am taking each line of the file and splitting it so that the first string is loaded as the movie name then the string following it is loaded as the actors' names. I have been able to take in the movie name and the first actor's name but I am not sure how I would continue down the line and load the rest of the actors' names when the number of actors varies in each line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
struct Node
{
  string actor;
  Node *next;
};

class LinkedList
{
  private:
    Node *head;
  public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(string);
    Node* new_actor_node(string);
    void append(string);
};

LinkedList :: LinkedList() {
  head = NULL;
}

LinkedList :: LinkedList(string head_actor) {
  head = new_actor_node(head_actor);
}

Node* LinkedList :: new_actor_node(string new_actor) {
  Node *new_node = new Node;
  new_node->actor = new_actor;
  return new_node;
}

void LinkedList :: append(string name) {
  Node *node = new Node;
  node->actor = name;

  if (head == NULL) {
    head = node;
    return;
  }
  
  Node *temp = new Node;
  temp = head;

  while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  
  temp->next = node;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i = 0;

  std::ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("cleaned_movielist.txt");
  
  LinkedList *movielist[140000];

  //Loading each index with NULL to create array
  for (int i = 0; i < 140000; i++) {
    movielist[i] = NULL;
  }

  if (myfile.is_open()) {
    string mystring;
    char *com, *actorname, *moviename;

    while (getline(myfile, mystring)) {
      com = strdup(mystring.c_str()); //copying string into c-style string
      moviename = strtok(com, " \t"); //loading the first string into moviename string variable
      actorname = strtok(NULL, " \t"); //loading the second string into actorname string variable

      cout << "Movie: " << moviename << endl;
      cout << "Actor: " << actorname << endl;
    }
  }
  
  myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Well one problem is that the code above only reads one actor for each movie, you need a second loop inside the first one to access all the actors for each move.

Comment: Another problem is that although you said you were going to  define an array of linked lists, what you have actually defined is an array of linked list pointers. There is no reason to use pointers here, just use this `LinkedList movielist[140000];`, no pointers necessary.

Comment: Hard to give much more help without knowing how `LinkedList` works. Also the idea of using a linked list to represent a movie is strange. Normally you would define a class to represent a movie. But maybe you have been told to do it that way (although that would be strange as well).

Comment: @john I was told to create an array of linked lists to represent a graph. Later I will have to run BFS on the graph to find the shortest path between two actors. The edges connecting the actors will be the movies.

Comment: OK, but there is still no reason to create an array of linked list pointers (and that is not what you were told to do). Pointers are necessary *internally* in a linked list, but once you have that, there's no reason to create *external* pointers to the linked lists.

Comment: It sound like you have things the wrong way around. If the goal is a graph with edges being movies then the actor should be the head of the linked list, and all the subsequent items should be the movies that actor is in,

Comment: @john You're right I do have it the wrong way around. I believe that would change the code below drastically, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it would (assuming you can't change the file format). You might have a look at C++ map classes, they would let you invert the file format more easily.

Comment: [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527), I take it? If you're having difficulty with an assignment, it's best to go to the instructor or TA so they're aware of where you are at with the material, and can provide background, additional explanations, and support for the class material. They are there to help you succeed.

Comment: This post is missing a question. What, specifically, do you need help on? Consult the [help] articles for more guidelines, especially "[ask]". See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

Well given the new code above and taking into account my comments, something like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {      
  LinkedList movielist[140000];
  int num_movies = 0;

  std::ifstream myfile("cleaned_movielist.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open()) {
    string mystring;
    while (getline(myfile, mystring)) {
      char* com = strdup(mystring.c_str());
      char* moviename = strtok(com, " \t");
      movieList[num_movies].append(new Node{moviename, NULL});
      for (;;)
      {
          char* actorname = strtok(NULL, " \t");
          if (actorname == NULL)
              break;
          movieList[num_movies].append(new Node{actorname, NULL});
      }
      free(con);
      ++num_movies;
    }
  }
}
```

Completely untested code.

The linked list class could do with some work. It should be possible to use `LinkedList` **without** knowing anything about `Node`. So I would expect

```
void LinkedList::append(string name);
```

not

```
void LinkedList::append(Node* name);
```

Your version forces the user to allocate nodes, but it's much cleaner if the `append` method allocates the node it needs internally, instead of expecting the user to do it.

Comment: I am mainly confused on what would go in the condition for the for loop. Would it run for the length of the string? I tried that but I might have implemented it wrong because it returned the first actor's name multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried my code above? It's correct I think.

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer Actually now I can see that your `append` function is bugged. It adds the new node to the front of the list, not to the end. So that needs fixing before you do anything else.